# Adding two columns in a single cell of excel using POI

Tags: apache-poi

I am creating an excel using poi jar and I have the following issue.

I have two columns coming from DB.

I have to add these columns in a single cell. one column with left alignment and one column with right alignment.

The cell should look like

```
   ----------------
   |A            B|
   ----------------
```

Any suggestions ???

Comment: Is there a reason why it has to be two cells merged into a single column? Wouldn't it be much better to have two columns, one left aligned, one right?

Comment: @Srinivas B: can you do the same in Excel manually. I have tried and failed. Gagravarr suggestion is feasible and easy to implement. If you want you can use boundary line color and background color, that will give you same visual.